# Jquery ui selectmenu loses value attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Suppose if am having

```
<select name="number" id="number">
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="three">3</option>

</select>
```

after applying `$('#number').selectmenu();` it converting to jquery ui dropdown style,select will be hidden and new span structure will come into picture,but in that span structure value attribute is missing,how can i retrieve the value attribute in the new span structure?

am expecting something like this.

```
<span class="ui-selectmenu-text" value="1">1</span>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin syntax to get the value of each option of your select :

```
$('#number').selectmenu({
  change: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.item.value);
  }
});
```

See the [Live Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbEayy)

jQuery UI doesn't really convert your select menu, it only create a new one with SPANs, and hide yours.

1st alert show you the selected value for the plugin select.
2, 3 and 4th alerts show you that you can still get you own select values. Now, you're free to use it as you wish.